# How to connect an event to a matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling

Using `matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection`, I have created a pyplot figure that shows a grid of hexagons: 
[image: hexagons]

Now, I want to make the plot interactive, i.e. add some form of event handling. In particular, I want to be able to hover my cursor over any of the hexagons and, when I do so, I want to fill all of the neighbouring hexagons with a certain color.

But, let's start easy: How can I connect a patch, meaning a hexagon, to an event?

I have stored the coordinates of the center points of each hexagon in a numpy-array. So, what I need is a way to tell me the index of the hexagon that I have clicked on, or my cursor is currently over. There are 100 hexagons alltogether. When I click on hexagon number 43, I simply need to get this index and, then, I think I know how to get my distance to all the neighbours. But how do I get this index?

Does anyone know?

Comment: Did you read the [picker demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html) or the [event handling guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/event_handling.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PatchCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection), like all collections, has a property [`contains()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.Collection.contains) that can tell you over which member of the collection (if any) the event was fired.

The only "trick" is that you have to make sure you initially have an array of facecolors that is the same size as the number of members in your collection, otherwise things will get messy. Here I use `PathCollection.set_facecolors()` after creation to make sure of that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection


def hover(event):
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        cont, ind = p.contains(event)
        if cont:
            idx = ind['ind'][0]
            colors = p.get_facecolors()
            colors[idx] = highlight_color
            p.set_facecolors(colors)
        else:
            p.set_facecolors([default_color] * N)
    fig.canvas.draw()


default_color = (0, 0, 1, 1)
highlight_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)

N = 10
r = 1
x, y = np.random.randint(10, 50, size=(2, N))
patches = [Circle((xi, yi), r) for xi, yi in zip(x, y)]
p = PatchCollection(patches)
p.set_facecolors([default_color] * N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(p)
ax.set_xlim(0, 50)
ax.set_ylim(0, 50)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thx so much! so `p.contains(event)` returns the boolean variable `cont` that is true, when the event has been fired inside an object contained in `PatchCollection p`. It returns the dictionary `ind` as well. This dictionary probably contains a key for each patch inside `PatchCollection p`. After each key, there is a list stored that contains all the events that have occured inside this particular patch. Question: What does the key `ind['ind']` give me?

Comment: [as per the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.Collection.contains), the dictionary contains `dict(ind=[list of patch indices])`. There could be several overlapping patches at the position of the event, so the list might contain several elements

Comment: okay. What is the point of having a dictionary that only contains one key ?

Comment: other types of objects can have other info returned in that dictionary